# How do I split lines with either of 2 conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a str like:

```
-110-108 -95 -92 -88 -87 -85 -75  -73 -69 -67 -59 -51 -49 -47 -42  -39 -35 -36 -36 -32 -27 -29 -32
```

**I need to split it into a list so that I get all the 24 elements like:**

```
["-110", "-108", "-95" ....]
```

I tried `line.split(" ")` but this doesn't work as I get the list as:

```
["-110-108" ...]
```

This is because there is no space between -110 & -108.

I tried splitting as `line.split("-")` but this has 2 problems:

The delim is lost, and if there is no negative sign, the whole number is treated as a string.

Like: `["-", "110", "-", "95" .... , "5 6 7"]` assuming there are positive numbers.

How do I split it exactly as the str contains 24 numbers and I need a list with all the 24 numbers as elements with magnitude.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

s = "-110-108 -95 -92 -88 -87 -85 -75  -73 -69 -67 -59 -51 -49 -47 -42  -39 -35 -36 -36 -32 -27 -29 -32"

l = [x for x in re.split("(-?\d+)",s) if x.rstrip()]

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['-110', '-108', '-95', '-92', '-88', '-87', '-85', '-75', '-73', 
 '-69', '-67', '-59', '-51', '-49', '-47', '-42', '-39', '-35', 
 '-36', '-36', '-32', '-27', '-29', '-32']
```

Explanation:

`re.split(pattern, string)` useses a pattern to split, the pattern I provided it with `(-?\d+)` means: optional `-` followed by 1 or more digits.

The list comprehension filters "empty" or "whitespace only" splits by discaring empty (== False) results using `if x.rstrip()`.

If you want to convert them as well, use:

```
l = [int(x) for x in re.split("(-?\d+)",s) if x.rstrip()]
```

---

Or - not as performant, creates lots of intermediate strings, you can "fix" it:

```
s = "-110-108 -95 -92 -88 -87 -85 -75  -73 -69 -67 -59 -51 -49 -47 -42  -39 -35 -36 -36 -32 -27 -29 -32"

for i in range(10): 
    s = s.replace(f'-{i}',f' -{i}') # replace any "-0","-1",...,"-9" 
                                    #        with " -0"," -1",...," -9" 

l = [x for x in s.split(" ") if x] # split by ' ' only use non-empty ones
```

---

You can split it yourself by iterating over the chars (still better then producing lots of intermediate strings)

```
s = "-110-108 -95 -92 -88 -87 -85 -75  -73 -69 -67 -59 -51 -49 -47 -42  -39 -35 -36 -36 -32 -27 -29 -32"

result = [] # complete list
tmp = [] # partlist
for c in s: # char-wise iteration 
    if c != '-':
        tmp.append(c)  
    else:
        if tmp:
            result.append(''.join(tmp).strip())
        tmp = ['-']

if tmp: # tmp not empty, and not yet added (last number in s)
    result.append(''.join(tmp))

print(result)
```

Comment: Great answer Patrick. I just stumbled on to this question. Because the `-` is optional, does that mean your solution would work seamlessly for positive numbers in the list as well? Looks like it does.

Comment: @rishijd yes - because that what normally happens ;) you need them for both - it wont work for positive ones if you add a `+` in front though - you would have to adjust the regexpatters for that - or simply replace all `+` by `' '` beforehand

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall()` and regex `-\d+`.

```
re.findall(r'-\d+', str)
```

Output:

```
['-110', '-108', '-95', '-92', '-88', '-87', '-85', '-75', '-73', '-69', '-67', '-59', '-51', '-49', '-47', '-42', '-39', '-35', '-36', '-36', '-32', '-27', '-29', '-32']
```